# Local machine not recognising docker node server ip address

Tags: node.js, docker

i am having trouble accessing my node server in my local browser which has started in my docker container.

**server**

```
var server = new (require('./static-server').Server)(8080);
server.app.use(server.express.static('./www'));
server.start(console.log);
```

**static-server**

```
var express = require('express'),
            http = require('http');

        this.ipaddress  =   process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
        this.port       =   process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT
                        ||  process.env.PORT
                        ||  8080;

        if (this.ipaddress === undefined) {
            console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
            this.ipaddress = '127.0.0.1';
        }

        this.app = express();
        this.server = http.createServer(this.app);
        this.express = express;

    }

    Server.prototype.start = function(cb) {
        this.server.listen(this.port, this.ipaddress, function () {
            cb(null, Date(Date.now)+' : Started server on '+this.ipaddress+':'+this.port);
        }.bind(this))   
    };

module.exports.Server = Server;
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM python:3.6.4-stretch
RUN apt-get update && \
    wget -q "https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_6.11.5-1nodesource1_amd64.deb" -O "nodejs.deb" && \
    dpkg -i "nodejs.deb" && \
    rm "nodejs.deb" && \
    npm install bower -g && \
    npm install gulp-cli -g && \
    apt-get clean

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 8080

RUN sh local-test.sh

ENTRYPOINT cd dist/; node server
```

I run the docker command. `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 ui`
but when i try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` the page is not working.

> This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Does your app is started correctly ? What are the logs of the container  ?

Comment: @Bastien Yes when i do docker run console shows "Started server on 127.0.0.1:8080". So it started correctly.

Comment: Did you try listening on all interfaces in your app, and let docker manage the localhost binding ? It might help.

Comment: @Bastien Yes i just tried changing my server from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and the page still does not send any data.

Comment: What is the output of `docker ps -a`? What platform do you use (Mac, Windows, Linux...)? Have you tried to access the ip of the container directly? (You can find the ip with `docker inspect <container_name>`)